# Importing large data from BigQuery to Firestore using Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client, google-admin-sdk

I am working on importing large data from a BigQuery dataset table into Firestore using Cloud Functions, all is well with small data tables of about 500 records. But the problem is with large data, for example, a table of about 40,000 records. From Firebase quota limit of 500 documents, they recommend using Batched writes which I have used but it still only inserts 500 documents, in logs, I see more than 500 documents have been created(I have logged auto-generated ID's) but I can not see them in Firestore.
I have configured the `enter code here`timeout to 540 seconds.
Help me look at my code and see where I am going wrong. Thanks

```
const {BigQuery} = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
const firebaseConfig =  require('firebase-admin');

firebaseConfig.initializeApp();

const firestoreDb = firebaseConfig.firestore();

var batchCommits = [];

var batch = firestoreDb.batch();

var counter = 0;

exports.fetchAdminTwo = (req,res) =>{
 var bigQuery = new BigQuery({ projectId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX' });

 var sqlStatement = 'SELECT id, id_admin1, description_en, description_fr, description_es, latitude, longitude FROM `fao-empres-re.empres_data.admin2`;';

 console.log('Triggering bigquery to execute sql statement');

 return bigQuery.query({query:sqlStatement}).then(results =>{
     var adminList = results[0];
     console.log('Query results:',adminList);

     res.send(adminList);

     adminList.forEach((admin,i) =>{
         var collectionRef = firestoreDb.collection('ref-admins-two').doc();
         batch.set(collectionRef,admin);
         console.log('Doc ID:',collectionRef.id,'Count:',counter++);
         if ((i + 1) % 500 === 0) {
             console.log(`Batch count: ${i + 1}`);
             batchCommits.push(batch.commit());
             batch = firestoreDb.batch();
             }
     });
     batchCommits.push(batch.commit());
     return Promise.all(batchCommits);

}).catch(error =>{
    console.log("Query error:",error);
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not resetting batchCommit to empty array before taking in next 500 batch.  Modify your code something like this.

```
if ((i + 1) % 500 === 0) {
             console.log(`Batch count: ${i + 1}`);
             batchCommits.push(batch.commit());
             batch = firestoreDb.batch();
             batchCommits = [];
             }
=
```

Comment: could please help me give more light, where do I reset the batchCommit from? Inside the loop or outside.

Comment: That last line Muloni in the code above.  Without that you are just adding to the array, so when you commit you repeatedly commit first 500 lines (the firestore batch limit)

Comment: I have added the reset line but still adding only 500 records and the execution times out without finishing all the records.